# Access slow when joining on Teradata SQL connections?

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, teradata

I have a simple Access database I use to create a number of reports. I've linked to a Teradata database server in our organization to pull some additional employee-level details. There is a simple left join on employee number, and all I pull is the name and the role.

The query without the connect takes maybe a minute or so to run and is very quick once loaded. Left joining on the Teradata connection slows everything down to a crawl. It can take 10 minutes or so to run the query through Excel. When the query is loaded in Access, scrolling through it is very slow.

I should note there's no performance issues with the Teradata server. I pull unrelated reports from the same and different tables, with complex joins and the speed is very quick.

I tried creating an even simpler query that does almost noting, and the performance issues are still there. Here is the code:

```
SELECT EMPL_DETAILS_CURR.NM_PREFX, EMPL_DETAILS_CURR.NM_GIVEN, 
MC.DT_APP_ENTRY, MC.CHANNEL_IND

FROM MC LEFT JOIN EMPL_DETAILS_CURR ON MC.EMP_ID = EMPL_DETAILS_CURR.EMP_ID;
```

There are only 7000 records in `MC`.

Comment: If you open the Access linked table in Design View and look at the [EMP_ID] field does Access recognize it as being indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are joining data between MS Access tables and Teradata tables the join has to be completed using the Microsoft JET Engine on your local machine. That means the data that exists in your Teradata tables is being brought down to your local machine to so that it can be joined.

If the tables are all on Teradata and accessed via linked tables in MS Access the join may still be occurring locally. I would suggest running the query as an ODBC Direct (I forget the exact term) query so that the SQL is passed on to Teradata to be executed and the results returned to MS Access when the query completes.

Comment: Some of the tables are local. Is there a more 'efficient' way to join local Access tables with Teradata tables? I resorted to downloading the three fields from the Teradata employee table, and importing that to Access. The download only took 2 minutes. The only issue is that the data is not 'live'.

Comment: You will have to move either the data in Access or the data you need out of Teradata. The most efficient manner would be for all the data to be in one place before joining it.